# Gnome-control-center (settings) not show in desktop 22.04

Tags: gnome, settings

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sf8gD.png)When I open settings, it's not showing in desktop. I will be try many times. I use many command just like remove, install, reinstall, update. But it's not showing.

[image]

Comment: Did you change a theme? What is the message if you open a terminal and type `gnome-settings`? Copy the text into your question **not** in the comments

Comment: Here is the link to [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1412419/edit) the question

Comment: it's said that " commands not found"

Comment: also have the same problem posted [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1411379/ubuntu-22-04-gnome-control-center-or-gnome-system-settings-not-opening)